# R - using dplyr mutate to allocate a proportion of a total number

Tags: r, dplyr, cumulative-sum

I have a data set of costs for rolling out 5G mobile infrastructure to serve different postcode areas:

```
observation <- c(1:10)
pop.d.rank  <- c(1:10)
cost  <- c(101:110)
all <- data.frame(observation,pop.d.rank,cost)
```

I then want to see, with a certain amount of annual investment, how many people can be covered by a certain amount of available capital. Let's say annual.investment is as follows:

```
annual.investment <- 500
```

Below I have then used dplyr to try to allocate this annual.investment to the different geotype areas in the data based on the cost variable :

```
all <- all %>% group_by(pop.d.rank) %>% 
       mutate(capital_allocated.5G = diff(c(0, pmin(cumsum(cost), annual.investment)))) %>%
       mutate(capital_percentage.5G = capital_allocated.5G / cost * 100)
```

However, the problem here is that the annual.investment amount of 500 is being allocated each time, to each observation in the data, rather than as a gross amount across all observations. Any suggestions for how I change this code to do this?

This is how the data should look afterwards:

```
observation <- c(1:10)
pop.d.rank  <- c(1:10)
cost  <- c(101:110)
capital_allocated.5G <- c(101, 102, 103, 104, 90, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
capital_percentage.5G <- c(100, 100, 100, 100, 86, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
example.output <- data.frame(observation,pop.d.rank,cost, capital_allocated.5G, capital_percentage.5G)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using `transform`

```
all <- transform(all, 
          capital_allocated.5G = diff(c(0, pmin(cumsum(cost), annual.investment))))
all <- transform(all,
                 capital_percentage.5G = capital_allocated.5G / cost * 100)
```

Or to avoid repeating your code, you can do this:

```
all <- with(all,{
    capital_allocated.5G = diff(c(0, pmin(cumsum(cost), annual.investment)))
    capital_percentage.5G = capital_allocated.5G / cost * 100
    return(cbind(all, capital_allocated.5G,
                 capital_percentage.5G))
})
```

They both give you the same output:

```
##   observation pop.d.rank cost capital_allocated.5G capital_percentage.5G
## 1            1          1  101                  101             100.00000
## 2            2          2  102                  102             100.00000
## 3            3          3  103                  103             100.00000
## 4            4          4  104                  104             100.00000
## 5            5          5  105                   90              85.71429
## 6            6          6  106                    0               0.00000
## 7            7          7  107                    0               0.00000
## 8            8          8  108                    0               0.00000
## 9            9          9  109                    0               0.00000
## 10          10         10  110                    0               0.00000
```

Also, your code works perfectly fine if you delete `group_by(pop.d.rank)`